# Apccelerator Titanium Bug Windows 10

Tags: node.js, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

I have recently instaled Appcelerator studio on a windows 10 pro laptop. I can't run a recently created mobile project. The following error is showing in console log:

```
FATAL ERROR: v8::ToLocalChecked Empty MaybeLocal.
```

It appears to be node js v8 engine. It's someone else having this issue?.

Edit: The error appears when building and running a project (Web or windows)

```
    Operating System
    Name                        = Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
    Version                     = 10.0.10586
    Architecture                = 64bit
    # CPUs                      = 8
    Memory                      = 8402731008
    Node.js
    Node.js Version             = 5.6.0
    npm Version                 = 3.6.0
    Titanium CLI
    CLI Version                 = 5.0.6
    Titanium SDK
    SDK Version                 = 5.2.0.GA
    SDK Path                    = C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.2.0.GA
    Target Platform             = mobileweb
    Command
    C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\User\.appcelerator\install\5.2.0\package\node_modules\titanium\lib\titanium.js build run --platform mobileweb --log-level trace --sdk 5.2.0.GA --project-dir F:\Test2 --deploy-type development --skip-js-minify --no-colors --no-progress-bars --no-prompt --prompt-type socket-bundle --prompt-port 18643 --config-file C:\Users\osc4r\AppData\Local\Temp\build-1457498056292.json --no-banner --project-dir F:\Test2
    [INFO] :   Found Titanium plugin id=ti.alloy version=1.0 
    FATAL ERROR: v8::ToLocalChecked Empty MaybeLocal.
```

Comment: Please provide some more details. What version of Titanium SDK are you using? What version of Android SDK are you targetting? Was this an emulator or device build?

Comment: Plus what NodeJS version?

Comment: titanium sdk and node versions are mentioned in answer I guess. and this is mobileweb project. :)

Comment: I face this problem as well. <br>
Then I try to look at the Appcelerator compatibility and found out that they only support Node.js from 0.10.x - 4.6.x <br>
http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix-section-src-29004837_TitaniumCompatibilityMatrix-Node.js
<br>
So, I uninstall my Node.js and reinstall it again with 4.6.x version from <a href="https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/">here</a>

Answer (score 0):

It seems your node version is not compatible. So you can check out the following blog link to install it in your machine

- http://titaniumsolution.blogspot.com/2016/12/fresh-installation-appcelerator-studio.html

Hope this helps.